# Gaussian Quadrature Error Estimate

Tags: quadrature, truncation-error

According to Chapter 5 of *Numerical Methods and Software* by Kahaner, et al. (1989), it can be shown that the error associated with Gaussian quadrature is

$\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)\,dx - \sum_{i=1}^n w_i\,f(x_i) =\frac{(b-a)^{2n+1} (n!)^4}{(2n+1)[(2n)!]^3} f^{(2n)} (\xi) , \qquad a < \xi < b.$

How is this error derived?

Comment: Expand f(x) into a power series up to terms $x^{2n}$.  Show that all lower order powers when approximated by Gaussian quadrature give the exact integral.

Comment: I understand the presence of the derivative order but not the expression that precedes it.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n w_if(x_i)$ is the Gauss quadrature approximation.

Comment: Yes, I understand that as well.  The part I am trying to derive is $\frac{(b-a)^{2n+1} (n!)^4}{(2n+1)[(2n)!]^3}$

Comment: I have not worked it out, but I suspect it is the approximation to the next term in a power series.

Comment: Does this error converges to zero ?